# How to write scipy sparse matrix on a file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a coo scipy sparse matrix 1000 x 12000 columns.
want to write on disk file following this format :
By row, all no-zeros columns :

col_id1:value    col_id2:value     ....
col_id2:value    ....

Is there a way to do in fast way ?
(without iterating manually)

Comment: Look at the `.rows` and `data` attributes of the `lil` format.  That has your information in the form of lists. You'd still have to iterate and format and write each line.

Comment: As a slight detour, you might want to look into the matrix market formats for sparse matrices. If for no other reason that scipy already contains functions to read/write those, see scipy.io.mmwrite/mmread.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what I suggested in the comment:

```
In [2]: from scipy import sparse
In [3]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2)
In [4]: M
Out[4]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [5]: print(M)
  (1, 9)    0.61465832998
  (8, 8)    0.894080347124
  (2, 7)    0.709001342736
  (3, 2)    0.809025517922
  (9, 8)    0.974650428753
  (7, 8)    0.495271225449
  (5, 6)    0.356408870324
  (0, 8)    0.57026318308
  (3, 6)    0.69919575217
  (5, 8)    0.226445982654
  (5, 1)    0.191857394963
  (7, 9)    0.121634028589
  (6, 6)    0.815836601813
  (7, 3)    0.585401171842
  (6, 7)    0.526762154792
  (6, 9)    0.775136319014
  (4, 1)    0.517647147906
  (0, 5)    0.484673192725
  (7, 5)    0.72827335905
  (2, 8)    0.527635893465
```

`lil` format collects values by row:

```
In [6]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [7]: Ml.rows
Out[7]: 
array([list([5, 8]), list([9]), list([7, 8]), list([2, 6]), list([1]),
       list([1, 6, 8]), list([6, 7, 9]), list([3, 5, 8, 9]), list([8]),
       list([8])], dtype=object)
In [8]: Ml.data
Out[8]: 
array([list([0.4846731927245771, 0.5702631830799726]),
       list([0.6146583299803253]),
       list([0.7090013427361257, 0.5276358934648013]),
       list([0.8090255179222732, 0.6991957521702542]),
       list([0.5176471479060225]),
       list([0.19185739496268694, 0.3564088703236009, 0.2264459826535451]),
       list([0.8158366018134895, 0.5267621547920701, 0.7751363190143352]),
       list([0.5854011718424482, 0.7282733590496102, 0.49527122544858804, 0.12163402858941941]),
       list([0.8940803471238159]), list([0.9746504287533381])], dtype=object)
```

Format lines according to your specs with a loop and list comprehension:

```
In [9]: for r,d in zip(Ml.rows, Ml.data):
   ...:     print(' '.join(['%s:%s'%(r1,d1) for r1,d1 in zip(r,d)]))
   ...:     
5:0.4846731927245771 8:0.5702631830799726
9:0.6146583299803253
7:0.7090013427361257 8:0.5276358934648013
2:0.8090255179222732 6:0.6991957521702542
1:0.5176471479060225
1:0.19185739496268694 6:0.3564088703236009 8:0.2264459826535451
6:0.8158366018134895 7:0.5267621547920701 9:0.7751363190143352
3:0.5854011718424482 5:0.7282733590496102 8:0.49527122544858804 9:0.12163402858941941
8:0.8940803471238159
8:0.9746504287533381
```

Substitute your file write line for the print.

We are looping 'manually', but access time to the data elements is relatively fast.  Certainly faster than indexing `M[i,j]`, which isn't possible with `coo` format anyways.

Fast row access via the `csr` format attributes is also possible, but requires a bit more knowledge of how that data is stored.

Your `:` syntax is not common, so you'll have do that formatting regardless.  How are intending to read this file?

Comment: Thanks, yes the file is intend to be read by external app.
Can we also do same with CSR format ?

1) isn't storing so many list in memory, kill the python interpreter memory ?

Comment: @Tensor, No one's complained about LIL being more of a memory hog than CSR.  But yes, you can use the `indptr` to slice the `indices` and `data` attributes.  That's been covered in SO questions about iterating on CSR rows.